# RxJS observable concat not working

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, reactivex

What is going on with the `concat` call? I know that if I replace `concat` by `merge` the code works correctly and the output is `foo` `bar` `qux` `quux`. I've read about Hot and Cold observables, and I know that for hot observables that might happen if the values are generated before the subscription, but my observables down there are [cold](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html), so I guess that's not the case.

```
const Rx = require('rxjs');

const observable1 = Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
  observer.next('foo');
  observer.next('bar');
  return observer;
});
const observable2 = Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
  observer.next('qux');
  observer.next('quux');
  return observer;
});
const result1 = observable1.concat(observable2);
result1.subscribe((x) => console.log(x));

// outputs
foo
bar
```

https://codepen.io/thiagoh/pen/WZyrRL

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe observer1 needs to `complete()`, then concat can start outputting observer2.

Ammended [CodePen](https://codepen.io/RMatsen/pen/pWKgeX)

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any source to confirm/explain why that is needed?

Comment: @thiagoh this a normal behavior of the `concat()` method. `Subscribe to observables in order as **previous completes**, emit values.` -- https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html

Comment: The marble diagrams are a good visual aid as well [Concat](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html)